# OO CSS/CSS components

Tags: html, css, oocss

I am wondering, which way is real objective oriented CSS where you can reuse components really quickly in a clean way.

---

Scenario 1:

*HTML:*

```
<button class="button button-submit">Submit</button>
```

*CSS:*

```
.button {
  /* basic styles */
}
.button-submit {
  /* special styles for submit button */
}
```

Scenario 2:

*HTML*

```
<button class="button submit">Submit</button>
```

*CSS*

```
.button {
  /* basic styles */
}
.button.submit {
  /* special styles */
}
```

---

I only see two negative aspects, one in each scenario.

In scenario 1 you might end up having really long class names.
In scenario 2, if you define .submit as it's own element/component, you end up with the old problem where you cannot reuse code fragments to stay the same in any place.

Comment: first one for sure, recommend you checkout SMACSS methodology

Answer (score 2):

Scenario 1 would probably be the more OO one but like all technologies and methodologies I would use the one that suits your needs best and you are going to enjoy writing.

Currently I am rebuilding an ecommerce platform from the ground up and when researching wanted to adopt similar methods. I ended up ignoring ways similar to your first example due to the long class names like you mentioned.

The idea behind all of it is to make writing code easier, quicker and more reusable. As soon as one of those factors is impacted too much while trying to satisfy the other, the whole idea behind trying them in the first place is voided.

Just to note this is a purely subjective answer and everyone is different.

Some good articles on the various methodologies and practices that I used to help make a decision:

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/16/a-new-front-end-methodology-bem/
- http://webuild.envato.com/blog/how-to-scale-and-maintain-legacy-css-with-sass-and-smacss/
- https://smacss.com/book/
- http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not OOP, you can however, use frameworks which allow to you code CSS in a DRY manner.

- [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)
- [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: DRY is important with or without LESS/SASS. It's very common for people to write terrible code even using less/sass as these are just tools and don't enforce anything. That being said, they are game changing :D

Comment: Yes that is true, clean code is always a good start :)

Comment: I left out SASS and LESS by choice because I believe, that it should be possible to have a clean structure even without a CSS precompiler :)

Comment: Yes of course, but if you want to reuse CSS properties multiple times and have their values as variables, that would require 1 single change in the future (for example) - then that can only be done with a CSS compiler. http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: @Lumio, of course you can, but preprocessors makes it much easier, if i were you i would use SASS + SMACSS

Comment: SMACSS is the keyword here! I'm looking at the specification

Comment: As @Evgeniy mentioned. It would make it easier... especially in the future. Imagine your website or app has a theme consisting of 3 base colours. In the future, however, you may want to change those colours. Potentially this could mean changing 3 variables with a precompiler like SASS. In "plain" CSS you would need to change every occurrence of each 3 colours.